# Integration of rational function with small coefficients

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I have to integrate a rational function $\frac{f(T)}{g(T)}$ which has really small numbers as coefficients.

like this: $\frac{3.4*10^{-23} p T^5 \sin ^2(2 \theta ) m_s^4}{\left(1.\, +e^p\right) \left(9.33*10^{-21} p^2 T^6 \cos (2 \theta ) m_s^2-2.43*10^{-21} p T^4 \cos (2 \theta ) m_s^2+m_s^4+2.18*10^{-41} p^4 T^{12}-1.13*10^{-41} p^3 T^{10}+1.47*10^{-42} p^2 T^8\right)}$

When I use `Integrate[f[T],{T,0,1000}]`, it never seem to give an answer, So I am thinking maybe it is due to small coeffcients because when I tried integrating without any coefficients just to check, it gave a value.

Is it possible to integrate this in Mathematica?

Is there any function which can take out the coefficients and make this function look like $\frac{a T^5}{b(cT^6+dT^4+...)}$?

And would it help in integrating the function better?

```
Remove["Global`*"];


$Assumptions = T \[Element] Reals &&  p \[Element] Reals && 0 < T < 1000

Subscript[T, i] = 1000;
Subscript[T, f] = 1;


Subscript[G, F] = 1.166*10^-11; 
Subscript[M, pl] = 2.4* 10^21;  
Subscript[\[Eta], B] = 6.05*10^-10; 


g[T_] = 1/4 *Piecewise[{{29, T < 1/2}, {43, 1/2 <= T < 105}, {57, 105 <= T < 139},{69,139 <= T < 170}, {247, 170 <= T <= 1270}}] // PiecewiseExpand

Subscript[f, a][p_, T_] = (1/(Exp[p/T] + 1)) 

\[CapitalDelta][p_] = (Subscript[m, s]^2/(2*p)) 


\[CapitalGamma][p_, T_] =Subscript[G, F]^2*p*T^4

Damped[p_, T_] = (\[CapitalGamma][p,T]/2) 

Subscript[V, Thermal][p_, T_] = -2*10^\[Minus]10*Subscript[G, F]* p*T^4          
Subscript[V, D][T_] =Sqrt[2]*Subscript[G, F]*Subscript[\[Eta], B]* (2*Zeta[3])/(4*Pi^2) *T^3 


Prob[p_, T_] = 1/2* ( (\[CapitalDelta][p]* Sin[2*\[Theta]])^2/((\[CapitalDelta][p]* Sin[2*\[Theta]])^2 + 
       Damped[p,T]^2 + (\[CapitalDelta][p]* Cos[2*\[Theta]] - Subscript[V, D][T] -Subscript[V, Thermal][p, T])^2)) // FullSimplify

h[p_, T_] = \[CapitalGamma][p, T]/2*Prob[p, T]


Subscript[RHS, redshift] = 
 h[(p*T)/Subscript[T, f] (g[T]/g[Subscript[T, f]])^(1/3), T]*Subscript[f, a][(p*T)/Subscript[T, f] (g[T]/g[Subscript[T, f]])^(1/3), T] //PiecewiseExpand 

Subscript[f, N] = Integrate[Subscript[RHS, redshift], {T, 1, 1000}]

test = Integrate[T^5/(T^8 - T^10 + T^12 - T^4 + T^6 + 1), {T, 1, 1000}] // N
```

Comment: `Integrate` is an exact solver and works best with exact coefficients, as a rule.

Comment: @MichaelE2 So should I substitute for all the variables like $p, m_s, \theta$? But I want to do a $p$ integration on this result. So, I want to keep $p$ as a variable

Comment: I'd try the symbolic thing (with appropriate `Assumptions`) first. The more parameters the harder it might be. If the parameters can cross branch points of the roots of the denominator when they vary, there also might be trouble.  You could also try substituting rational approximation for some parameters.

Comment: Sometimes using arbitrary precision numbers helps (e.g. `SetPrecision[integrand, 16]`). — Gratuitous example of failure with inexact coefficients: Both `Integrate[1/Expand[(x + Sqrt[2.])^2], x]` and `Integrate[Rationalize[1/Expand[(x + Sqrt[2.])^2]], x]` produce dissatisfying results. They work with ``Sqrt[2.`16]``, though.  With too high a `SetPrecision[]`, it fails again: ``Integrate[SetPrecision[1/Expand[(x + Sqrt[2.`])^2], 32], x]``