# Solve[] arbitrarily adding orders of magnitude which cancel?

Tags: equation-solving

Define the variables

```
m0 = .1349766;
mp = .13957018;
mX = (2 mp + 3 m0)/2;
```

Now suppose we wish to solve the following equation for equation `Ep`:

```
sols = Solve[(2 E0 Ep - 4 (E0 + Ep) mX + 4 mX^2 + m0^2)/(Sqrt[Ep^2 - mp^2] Sqrt[E0^2 - m0^2]) == 1, Ep]
```

Then, Mathematica returns

```
{{Ep -> (1.07446*10^47 + E0 (-4.59436*10^47 + 4.42011*10^47 E0) -  0.5 Sqrt[-3.79456*10^92 + E0 (2.32699*10^93 + E0 (1.73795*10^94 + E0 (-1.27726*10^95 + 1.89274*10^95 E0)))])/(3.05309*10^47 + E0 (-8.84022*10^47 + 4.84611*10^47 E0))}, 
{Ep -> (1.07446*10^47 + E0 (-4.59436*10^47 + 4.42011*10^47 E0) + 0.5 Sqrt[-3.79456*10^92 + E0 (2.32699*10^93 + E0 (1.73795*10^94 + E0 (-1.27726*10^95 + 1.89274*10^95 E0)))])/(3.05309*10^47 + E0 (-8.84022*10^47 + 4.84611*10^47 E0))}}
```

which is fine, I guess. But, as you can see, it's introduced a bunch of factors of $10^{47}$ which cancel everywhere. This seems to me to be totally meaningless and could present a huge numerical hassle especially since none of my parameters are even remotely close to $10^{47}$.

So I guess my question is, how do I get Mathematica to stop introducing arbitrary factors of huge numbers in `Solve[]`?

Comment: They are not "introduced" arbitrarily; they are just what comes out of the calculation using your machine-precision numbers. Can m0 and mp be expressed symbolically instead?

Comment: Yea, i can solve it symbolically just  fine

Comment: What are the arbitrary precision values of m0 and mp then?

Comment: maybe work with `{m0, mp} = Rationalize[{m0, mp}, 0];`?

Comment: [`Solve` is an exact solver and works best with exact coefficients, as a rule.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/241155/integration-of-rational-function-with-small-coefficients#comment608722_241155)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps this will work better?

```
mX = (2 mp + 3 m0)/2;

sols = Solve[(2 E0 Ep - 4 (E0 + Ep) mX + 4 mX^2 + 
      m0^2)/(Sqrt[Ep^2 - mp^2] Sqrt[E0^2 - m0^2]) == 1, Ep];

FullSimplify[sols]/.{m0 -> 0.1349766, mp -> 0.1397018}
```

Comment: Thanks! That works as I hoped, but what if I can't solve for it symbolically? I'm feeding this result directly into ```NIntegrate[]```.  Cant introducing these huge numbers numerical issues down the road?